# Python function to create a plot for each region in list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a series of plots in pandas go through and make a multiple line plot of each region.

`regions = list(data.region.unique())`

This gives a list of the 10 regions. Then I have my plotting function:

```
for region in regions:
    df2 = data.loc[data['region'] == region]
    sns.lineplot(x = df2['date'], y = df2['totals'], hue = df2['state'])
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.) 
plt.legend()
```

But this plots all of the states into an unreadable mess. Also, the legend os not outside of the graph, which is another problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should create a `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` inside the `for` loop, and pass `ax=ax` to `sns.lineplot`.

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you!

`for region in regions:
    df2 = data.loc[data['region'] == region]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.lineplot(x = df2['date'], y = df2['totals'], hue = df2['state'], ax = ax)`